# как заменить символы в колнке ms access

Tags: ms-access

есть столбец где записи начинаются в одних строках с русской `М` в других с англ `М`. нужен запрос который заменит русские на англ-е

```
UPDATE table SET column1= Replace(column1,"М","M")
WHERE column1 like "М%";
```

В like указана русская `М`. Запрос не находит строки. При обычном поиске по таблице русская находится.

Comment: Зачем вообще тут нужен Like? всё равно задача одноразовая, так что не будет большой беды, если обработаются все записи.

Comment: А ещё - в MS Jet в качестве символа-шаблона "любое количество любых символов" используется звёздочка `*`, а не знак процента.